# Sense Hat RGB Code

Tags: python, sense-hat

I am a new programmer, trying to learn python. I am using the sense hat to mess around with, I want to make it like rotate RGB colors. I am using the sense.set_pixel and passing in the x,y and r,g,b arguments(?). It's not setting any pixels however. Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import random

sense = SenseHat()

def rainbow():
  x = random.randrange(8)
  y = random.randrange(8)
  r = random.randrange(256)
  g = random.randrange(256)
  b = random.randrange(256)
  while True:
      sense.set_pixel(x,y,r,g,b)

rainbow()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't own a sense hat but try these tips:

Install the sense hat

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sense-hat
sudo reboot
```

Read the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/sense-hat/api/)

Try a different script:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

X = [255, 0, 0]  # Red
O = [255, 255, 255]  # White

question_mark = [
O, O, O, X, X, O, O, O,
O, O, X, O, O, X, O, O,
O, O, O, O, O, X, O, O,
O, O, O, O, X, O, O, O,
O, O, O, X, O, O, O, O,
O, O, O, X, O, O, O, O,
O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O,
O, O, O, X, O, O, O, O
]

sense.set_pixels(question_mark)
```

Run the Python script as root (using `sudo`)